# Очистка старых данных из textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Как реализовать очистку старой информации из "логового" textBox, к примеру с выше 1000 строк или, там, больше 20 000 символов, не теряя свежие данные?

То есть в textBox1 добавляются (`textBox1.AppendText(text + "\n");`) все комментарии о работе, спустя какое-то  время, в нем может быть пару тысяч строк, но при этом важны только данные о последних действиях. Как счищать лишнее?

Comment: Так удалять строки из начала

Comment: Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq однострочник (неффективно, зато просто и коротко)

```
myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text
    .Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Reverse()
    .Take(3) // сколько вам надо с конца строк
    .Reverse()
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc,s)=>acc.AppendLine(s))
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
if (textBox.Lines.Length > 1000)
{
    var index = textBox.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(0, index + Environment.NewLine.Length);
}
textBox.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
```

Или можно взять `ListBox` вместо `TextBox`. С ним код будет выглядеть так:

```
if (listBox.Items.Count > 1000)
{
    listBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
listBox.Items.Add(text);
```