# Ведение логов через label. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим, что в интерфейсе есть label1. Нужно чтобы велись логи. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку и внизу интерфейса пишется: "successful click".

Проблема: Не знаю как реализовать добавление текста с новой строки.

Comment: `mylabel.Text += Environtment.NewLine + "my text from new line"`; Только учтите, что 1) Это медленно 2) Так никто не делает, пишите лучше логи в файл

Comment: Ну мне для красоты интерфейса надо. :)

Comment: @tym32167 Вот у меня ещё одна проблема, как узнать что текст в label вышел за границы и его обнулить?

Comment: без понятия, более того, это звучит как отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/902991/184217

Comment: Создайте не `Label`, а `TextBox`, сделайте его только для чтения, у него при переполнении строк появится скролл.